# How to get a git tag message from the Github API

Tags: api, github, github-api

I'm trying to get tag messages from the Github API. It [says here](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/) I'm supposed to use this URL:
https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/tags/940bd336248efae0f9ee5bc7b2d5c985887b16ac

But I get "Not found" there, even if I try my own repo:
https://api.github.com/repos/richbrat/testrepo/git/tags/6cec7db2ae2d0213644480ba58bcc4a277ae8a2b

I'm using the [node-github package](http://mikedeboer.github.io/node-github/) with an oauth token and it's working really well for the "repos" calls but "gitdata" doesn't seem to work. Checking the headers I get back gives me a hint though:

```
... "x-oauth-scopes":"user, public_repo, repo, gist","x-accepted-oauth-scopes":"repo" ...
```

Gitdata seems to be outside my scope. Is it possible to get it into my scope or is there another solution to get tag messages?

Comment: The API endpoint you are using is available only for annotated tags. Is the tag object you are trying to fetch an annotated Git tag or a lightweight Git tag? Also, is 940bd336248efae0f9ee5bc7b2d5c985887b16ac the SHA of the tag objet itself (it needs to be)? Scopes are not the problem here -- you're using a token which has user, public_repo, repo and gist scopes, and the API endpoint you are using requires only repo scope.

Comment: I've created some tags using 'git tag -a v1.0 -m "My tag message"' – that's an annotated tag right?
Is it possible to get a SHA from a tag, does it have it's own SHA? I mean, if I list tags from a repo it is only showing me the SHA:s from the commit that I tagged.

Comment: If you execute "git show v1.0" you should see the commit to which the tag is pointing to (and the commit's SHA). However, if you execute "git show-ref v1.0" you should see the SHA of the tag object itself.

Comment: Aha nice! I guess this is where I can get the tag ref from the API: http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/  
I'll try it later, thanks for your response Ivan!

Comment: Yep, the Git Refs API should also tell you the SHA of the tag object, if it's an annotated tag. Happy to help!

Comment: @RichardB, how did you get it to work, if you remember? From the remarks here I'm not sure what you changed? ty!

Comment: @AnneTheAgile Richard used https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/refs#get-a-reference=, meaning `/refs/tags/myTag`. See a [concrete example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72439130/6309).