# How to get Single tag Information using GitHub Api?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I was using Github tags Api for fetching the information about the tags. [Git Tags Document.](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/tags#get-a-tag)

While doing so I was able to fetch the information of all the tags using https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/git/tags , But I want to find the information of a single tag. In the documentation, it was given to use  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/git/tags/TAG_SHA for fetching the required tag, but while doing so it show an error as-

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/git#get-a-tag"
}
```

Kindly help me to find the particular tag information.

Comment: Is the tag in question a *lightweight* tag or an *annotated* tag?

Comment: Its an annotated tag.

Comment: OK, then `git rev-parse <tag>` will give you its hash ID. Not sure what GitHub API would do that. Presumably once you have the hash ID, you present that hash ID to the GitHub API end-point you mentioned.

Comment: I have tried this approach as well, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Hm. I can try it for a tag I can find, such as `v2.36.1` in the Git repository for Git. This tag `rev-parse`-es as `89753168fae3a40aa6edad841d68a912498fd7c2` so the URI / URL for this is https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/git/tags/89753168fae3a40aa6edad841d68a912498fd7c2 -- and going there gets me a JSON data dump, so it all seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Note: `/git/tags` does not list tags. It allows to [create a new tag](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/tags#create-a-tag-object=).

- Only `/tags` list tags: https://api.github.com/repos/VonC/gitcred/tags
- And `/git/refs/tags` list annotated tags *refs* Ie `tags/xxx`):
  https://api.github.com/repos/VonC/gitcred/git/refs/tags

https://api.github.com/repos/VonC/gitcred/git/refs/tags/v0.5.5

Meaning the proper API is [Get a reference / `get/repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/ref/{ref}`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/refs#get-a-reference=), with:

> The `:ref` in the URL must be formatted as:
>
> - `heads/<branch name>` for branches and
> - `tags/<tag name>` for tags.

Answer (score 0):

Since the tag you're looking for is an `annotated` tag, you can use the URL you mentioned above: https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/git/tags/TAG_SHA

The important piece here is the `TAG_SHA`.  This is NOT the `COMMIT_SHA`.  It's actually the SHA related to the annotated tag object.

To determine the `TAG_SHA` from a `TAG` name, you can use this API endpoint:
https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/git/refs/tags/TAG_NAME

This returns a json response like this:

```
{
  "ref": "refs/tags/TAG_NAME",
  "node_id": "NODE_ID",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/git/refs/tags/TAG_NAME",
  "object": {
    "sha": "TAG_SHA",
    "type": "tag",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/git/tags/TAG_SHA"
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `object.url` is the `git/tags/TAG_SHA` endpoint referenced above that returns details for the annotated tag:

```
{
  "node_id": "NODE_ID",
  "sha": "TAG_SHA",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/git/tags/TAG_SHA",
  "tagger": {
    "name": "TAGGER_NAME",
    "email": "TAGGER_EMAIL",
    "date": "TAGGER_DATE"
  },
  "object": {
    "sha": "COMMIT_SHA",
    "type": "commit",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/git/commits/COMMIT_SHA"
  },
  "tag": "TAG_NAME",
  "message": "TAG_MESSAGE\n",
  "verification": {...}
}
```